# c++ string element conversion to int

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    vector<string> tab;
    tab.push_back("1234");
    cout << tab[0][0];// -> 1
    if (int(tab[0][0]) == 1) {
        cout << "test";
    }
}
```

why does this comparison not work? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `if (tab[0][0] == std::to_string(1)) {....}` because you cannot cast string to int

Comment: @NutCracker You mean `if (tab[0] == std::to_string(1)) {....}`, `tab[0][0]` is a character.

Comment: @john actually `if (tab[0][0] == '1') {....}` would be enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'1'` the character is not the same as `1` the integer.

To do your comparison write

```
if (tab[0][0] == '1') {
```

Specifically when you convert a character to an integer what you get is the *encoding* of the character. If you are using ASCII (which is very likely) then the encoding of `'1'` is 49.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, ...) and digits (`'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, ...).

They look the same when you print them, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `tab[0][0]` will evaluate to the first *character* of the first string in the `tab` vector. Note that this is a character representation (probably ASCII, but not necessarily so), which will not have the numerical value of `1` (it will have the value `49` if your system uses ASCII).

So, in your `if` test, you need to compare the value with a **character literal** rather than an **integer literal**, like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<std::string> tab;
    tab.push_back("1234");
    std::cout << tab[0][0];// -> 1
    if (int(tab[0][0]) == '1') { // Compare to the character '1'!
        std::cout << "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Want To Convert A String To A Number Use The Function Atoi()

```
std::string str = "12345";
int num = std::atoi(str.c_str());
// num = 12345
```

If You Want one Single Character Not a char*

```
std::string str = "12345";
int num = str[0] - '0';
// num = 1
```